# Is there any way to use the return value of custom python script to django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to run a custom python script and return its value to template. The return function from custom script is returning value in the script but i can't use it in template.

This is my custom script which returns the label value:

```py
def genre(f):
    K.clear_session()
    model = joblib.load('music/finalized_CNNmodel.sav')
    print(model.layers[0].input_shape)

    mel_spec(f)
    test_image=image.load_img(f'media/{f.file.name}.png', target_size=(256,256), color_mode='rgb')
    test_image=image.img_to_array(test_image)
    test_image=np.expand_dims(test_image,axis=0)
    result=model.predict(test_image)
    label = np.argmax(result)

    return label
```

I'm calling this function through views as:

```py
def model_form_upload(request):
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(request.FILES)
            newdoc = Document(file=request.FILES['file'])
            newdoc.save()
            print(newdoc.file.name)
            genre(newdoc)
            return render(request,'music/result.html', 
                         {'documents':documents,'form':form})
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()

    return render(request,'music/result.html', 
                 {'documents':documents,'form':form})
```

This is my template:

```py
{% if genre.label == 0 %}
  CLASSICAL
{% elif genre.label == 1 %}
   DOHORI
{% else %}
   POP
{% endif %}
```

I expected to show the result in the template but the return value is not passing to the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake on my side. If in case anyone is wondering i forgot to assign variable to the function in my views:

```py
label = genre(newdoc) 
context ={'documents':documents,'form':form,'label':label}
```

After this i was ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

Without a sample output of `genre()` function and full template, I'm making a guess.

You should pass the result of `genre()` function to the template as follows:

```
def model_form_upload(request):
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(request.FILES)
            newdoc = Document(file=request.FILES['file'])
            newdoc.save()
            print(newdoc.file.name)
            return render(
                request,'music/result.html', 
                {'documents':documents,'form':form, 'genre':genre(newdoc)}
            )
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()

    return render(request,'music/result.html', 
                 {'documents':documents,'form':form})
```

Comment: Thanks i realized a bit later.